# isolate physical interface - router

Tags: linux, router, vmware-esxi

Environment:
-single physical server with 2 NIC (physical) interfaces
-installed ESXi 5.0
-NIC1 connected to internet (modem)
-NIC2 connected to Cisco switch (LAN)
-virtual machine (debian) installed on esxi - should be a router

ToDo:
The virtual machine (debian) should take care of internet access of whole network (should be a router). I'd like to isolate the two physical NICs so ONLY the router could access NIC1 (the internet) and any other PC (VM or physical) could access internet ONLY via the router (debian)

I'm a newbie in ESXi.

How to do that?

Comment: Be a pro, get some training, this site's for pro's not beginners.

Comment: Everyone is beginner in some field. I'm in ESXi, not in networking, linux administrating etc. Dont be rough

Comment: Two vswitches, 0 & 1, 0 with one port group on the ext NIC, 1 with a vmkernel port group and the int traffic, give the VM two vNICs, one on each port group. The end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowlege, you can't dedicate a nic to a vm  the way you can a LUN. Or if you can, it requires supported hardware for the feature.

Keep in mind that other vms will not be able to access that nic unless it is configured to have that nic in the settings. You aren't using vlans, so won't be able to aggregate both nics into a virtual switch. They will be separately assigned entities. So long as you control vm config from the esx side, this should not be a concern.